# AUCTex coloring

Tags: color, auctex

How would you configure your .emacs file to get more coloring options in Emacs+AucTeX?

My .emacs configuration returns this result:

[image]

Comment: Which theme are you using for Emacs generally?  (I installed and use the kaolin themes, which look good in AucTeX, but many others are good too.)

Comment: I don't see `kaolin-themes`, whit `M-x package-install RET` y have `kmb`

Comment: Which version of Emacs do you have? Is it recent enough that `M-x load-theme RET wombat` works?

Comment: I installed yesterday GNU Emacs 26.2. But before I had version 24 and I couldn't install the themes either.

Comment: Probably posting on emacs.stackexchange.com/ is a better choice